# R ancova "Error in if" + "warning in min/max"

Tags: r, statistics

I'm new to R (and coding mostly), since SPSS doesn't provide any models for my highly skewed and not normal data. My understanding is that the robust ancova options of the WRS2 package can help me overcome these issues, however, I constantly get an error message when trying either the ancova() or ancboot() functions.

To give you an idea of my dataset (just a small sample, for one ancova)

```
    > str(datappn)
    'data.frame':   26 obs. of  60 variables:
    $ Conditie                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Controle","Interventie": 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 ...
    $ CBIQA_zelfevaluatie_daily.1: num  4.5 4.6 4.3 4.2 4.9 4.2 4.8 5.7 4.6 4.8 ...
    $ CBIQA_zelfevaluatie_daily.2: num  4.1 4.8 4.6 4.1 5.2 4 4.6 5.8 4.6 4.3 ...
```

The error I get is this:

```
    > ancovaZED <- ancova(CBIQA_zelfevaluatie_daily.2 ~ CBIQA_zelfevaluatie_daily.1 + Conditie, data = datappn)
    Warning in min(sub[vecn >= 12]) :
       no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
    Warning in max(sub[vecn >= 12]) :
       no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
    Error in if (nuhat < 2) stop("The degrees of freedom must be greater than or equal to 2") : 
       missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I have tried including fr1 = 0.3, fr2=0.3, pts=NA etc., but all with the same results. Same when I try ancova the direct way:

```
    ancova(CBIQA_zelfevaluatie_daily.2 ~CBIQA_zelfevaluatie_daily.1 + Conditie, data = datappn)
```

(everywere I say ancova, you can also read ancboot, since that brings up the same problems)

Does anyone have any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code is technically correct. I can't say for sure without seeing your full dataset, but I suspect you have too few points and/or not enough variation in your data to do some of the internal calculations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Esther! It's good to know that not my code, but my data might be the cause of this problem. It's quite possible I don't have enough datapoints (N=26, evenly spread over 2 conditions) and the ones I have are highly skewed on almost all measures, possibly causing a lack of variation (which isn't weird, since the main object of this study are eating disorders).

(Although, now I'm back at square one and looking for a correct way to get an answer for my research questions, I am doubting bwtrim() since I can get it to run, but might still violate the robust assumptions)

Comment: No worries, you might try asking about your analysis over at [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks again, Esther. Although I think I found a solution for this problem, another one popped up. I have asked the question over at Cross-Validated :)